# Do something after a function was called

Tags: python-3.x

I am using loguru for logging in my application, while every log was recorded I will record a same log message into an list. Below are the example:

```
log_list = []

logger.trace("Log first time")
log_list.append("Log first time")
...do something...
logger.trace("Log second time")
log_list.append("Log second time")
```

Is that possible to make log_list.append() run after every call of logger.trace() without write a new line ? Something like add an EventHandler in logger.trace onCall event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the [logger docs](https://loguru.readthedocs.io/en/stable/overview.html#no-handler-no-formatter-no-filter-one-function-to-rule-them-all), there's a lot of info about event handlers that can be attached using the [`add()` method](https://loguru.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/logger.html#sink).

So something like this should work :

```py
from loguru import logger

log_list = []

handler_id = logger.add(lambda msg: log_list.append(msg), level='TRACE')

logger.trace("Log first time")
# ...do something...
logger.trace("Log second time")

print(log_list)
```

Taking a look at that page in the docs will definitely help, the function seems to have many many more possiblilities

Comment: Yes this is exactly what I want. Thanks